# is LIKE, but with int representing an string on which should be checked

Tags: php, sql, filter, mariadb, sql-like

Let's say I have a table (`tableA`) with a column `Kwaliteit`, which will hold an `int` value (`0, 1, 2, 3`) that will represent some string values.

These string values are stored serialized in an another table (`tableB`) like this:

```
a:4:{i:0;s:4:"Goed";i:1;s:5:"Matig";i:2;s:6:"Slecht";i:3;s:12:"Afgeschreven";}
```

Which will give a PHP array like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Goed
    [1] => Matig
    [2] => Slecht
    [3] => Afgeschreven
)
```

The thing is, I want to filter on `Afgeschreven`. So I insert that in the `LIKE` part of the query, but that isn't working because there's an `int` instead of the `string` in `tableA`.

How can I bypass this problem? Can I like alter the column value temporarily with the string value to do the filter?

**Edit**
Here's the structure of `tableA` (Kist)

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Kist` (
  `idKist` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `idKistType` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Tag1` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `Tag2` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `VisueelNr` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `Bouwjaar` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `kwaliteit` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `Actief` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idKist`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=982 ;

INSERT INTO `Kist` (`idKist`, `idKistType`, `Tag1`, `Tag2`, `VisueelNr`, `Bouwjaar`, `kwaliteit`, `Actief`) VALUES
(1, 1, '0086-1700-0000-0000-0000-371E', '0086-1700-0000-0000-0000-3868', '0', '', 3, 0),
(2, 1, '0086-1700-0000-0000-0000-413F', '0086-1700-0000-0000-0000-409A', '0', '', 0, 1);
```

And `tableB` (Instellingen)

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Instellingen` (
  `idInstellingen` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Instelling` varchar(45) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `Waarde` longtext COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  PRIMARY KEY (`idInstellingen`),
  UNIQUE KEY `Instelling_UNIQUE` (`Instelling`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=220 ;

INSERT INTO `Instellingen` (`idInstellingen`, `Instelling`, `Waarde`) VALUES
(200, 'kistKwaliteit', 'a:4:{i:0;s:4:"Goed";i:1;s:5:"Matig";i:2;s:6:"Slecht";i:3;s:12:"Afgeschreven";}');
```

The serialized value is stored in column `Waarde`

Comment: You have a table where one column is a string *(VARCHAR?)* and and example of that string (in one row) is `'a:4:{i:0;s:4:"Goed";i:1;s:5:"Matig";i:2;s:6:"Slecht";i:3;s:12:"Afgeschreven";}'`?  Then you want to search that table for all rows where that string has the string `'"Afgeschreven"'` within it?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're trying to filter on. Can you post some sample data on which you're trying to apply the filter? As I understand it if you want to know which rows have `Afgeschreven`, you should filter on `Kwaliteit=3` without any `LIKE` clause. Seeing some sample data might help clarify what you're trying to find.

Comment: @MatBailie Sorry if I wasn't clear enough. In `tableA` I have these `integers` which represents `strings` that are stored `serialized` in `tableB`. I want to filter with an `string` on `tableA`

Comment: Precisely why we try to persuade people to nromalise their database structure rather than storing json/serialised/comma-separated data in columns.... you'll have to read the json, decode it, work out which value your input represents, and then build your query, precisely because you've eliminated the option of using a JOIN by not normalising

Comment: @MarkBaker Agree. This is that case.

Comment: @MarkBaker I can't argue with that! But something about working with decisions made by others.... But maybe if this isn't possible, I could change there opinion...

Comment: @Mathlight - There appears to be no foreign key relationships between your tables?  What is the explicit relationship between the tables?  How do I know which row (or rows) in `kist` are related to which row (or rows) in `Instellingen`?

Comment: @MatBailie I'm not trying to scare you... But there isn't any relationship between these 2.....

Comment: @Mathlight - But you said `In tableA I have these integers which represents strings that are stored serialized in tableB`?  I take that to mean that there is / should be a relationship between the tables?

Comment: @MatBailie There's an relation as in PHP combines everything together and makes sure the string is outputted instead of the integer

Comment: Are you using MariaDB's Dynamic Columns?

Comment: @RickJames no, I don't use them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you saved the mapping of ints to strings for the kwaliteit values serialised as text, it's not possible to select based on the text/label in MySQL.

What you could do, for example, is create a new table Kwaliteit, with 2 columns, id and label. Then you could join that new table with the Kist table ON Kist.kwaliteit = Kwaliteit.id 
The where condition would be with those column names WHERE label = 'Afgeschreven'

Another possibility would be changing the Instellingen table: Split the Waarde column into 2, id and value. That would mean 4 rows in the table for the kwaliteit in that table:

```
(200, 'kistKwaliteit', '0', 'Goed'), 
(200, 'kistKwaliteit', '1', 'Matig'), 
(200, 'kistKwaliteit', '2', 'Slecht'), 
(200, 'kistKwaliteit', '3', 'Afgeschreven')
```

The request could be

```
SELECT * FROM Kist WHERE kwaliteit = 
(SELECT id FROM Instellingen WHERE Instelling = 'kistKwaliteit' AND value = 'Afgeschreven')
```

If you want to keep the database structure the same, you have to handle getting the ID that matches the quality you want on the PHP side. For example if it's something a user can chose via dropdown, make the value the ID as saved in the serialised array, and use the labels just as labels. Or when getting passed the string for the quality, first get the serialized array from the DB to find the ID, then use that ID in the SELECT.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. That last part have put me up to thinking about it from an whole new perspective...

Answer (score 2):

What you have is supposedly more or less this:

```
select * from tablea where kwaliteit = 'Afgeschreven';
```

Which doesn't work, as kwaliteit  is the code, not the string. What you are looking for is about this:

```
select * from tablea where kwaliteit =
 (select kwaliteit from tableb where text = 'Afgeschreven');
```

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear enough. I've updated the question with some database data. This will show that this isn't possible right now (only if where going to make an new table)

Comment: Okay. Can you make this table? MariaDB enhances the realational model with NoSQL. However, this shouldn't lead to neglect the fundamental things an RDBMS provides. When using codes, there should be a lookup table and a foreign key constraint on it.

Comment: And nonetheless: You do have the value 'Afgeschreven' which you want to use to filter data in your table. How come you have this string, but not string's code as well? When a user selects 'Afgeschreven', your app should know that this is code 3 and use this to build the query.

Comment: I thought so about making the table... And the user will fill in the filter in an textbox. So It can also be `Af` or something completely irrelevant, just because there filtering on some other column...

Comment: Okay. So build that table then and change the SQL to something like `select * from tablea where kwaliteit in
 (select kwaliteit from tableb where text like @search);` Or use a join, if you want to show the kwaliteit  string in the results.

Comment: Thank you for thinking with me. Although your answer is right, it didn't lead to fixing this problem (thanks to other team members decisions....). That's why I accepted the others answer, although your answer could help people out in the future.

Answer (score -1):

You can't. You should do search by array key (aka 3 or 2), this will also speed up query.

For updated structure you can try using:

`select * from Instellingen where Waarde like "%Afgeschreven%";`